# iOS storyboard how to present a controller from right using "push" style without navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I got a regular full screen view controller defined in storyboard. It has no navigation controller. When a user taps a button, I would like to present another view controller wrapped in a navigation controller. Currently I'm using modal segue. I would like this modal transition to happen from the right using "push" style. I will be handling the "back"/popping events myself.

So far I have not been able to figure this out. Is there some custom segue class that can simulate pushing when there's no navigation controller?

Comment: Why not to use UINavigationController but hide navigationBar?

Comment: It creates storyboard layout complications, because I cannot hide the bar in one controller (44px more screen) and show it in subsequent controllers (44px less space). This is why I want to push a navigation controller - so I get WYSWYG behavior for storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code:

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = self ;
UIViewController *destinationController = objdestinationViewController;

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

[self.view addSubview:destinationController.view];
```

Comment: I remember this code from the view transitions example. Now I need to figure out how to create a custom storyboard transition using this snippet

Comment: make a object of UIStoryboardSegue

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a technique where you work out your screen size. Then, you work out a rect for the center of your screen, the right of the screen, and the left of the screen, then animate.

This code is a function that will animate as if a new view is pushing a current view out to the left. `viewComing` is the view that's arriving into view. `viewGoing` is the currently visible view.

```
- (void) animateToLeft:(UIView*)viewComing andViewGoing:(UIView*)viewGoing {
    CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGRect left = screenRect;
    CGRect center = screenRect;
    CGRect right = screenRect;

    left.origin.x -= screenRect.size.width;
    right.origin.x += screenRect.size.width;

    viewGoing.frame = center;
    viewComing.frame = right;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        viewComing.frame = center;
        viewGoing.frame = left;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the navigation controller it self and there is a property for hiding the navigation bar see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). look for navigationBarHidden.